# @Bean works without @Configuration. How can it still work without @Configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The bottom code is my Spring Batch program code. when you see the bottom, you can see the code's problem. there is no `@Configuration`. originally, it was impossible to inject to dependency classes, but it was injected.

The first image is my project explorer.
I will inject dataSource to dataSource in `BatchJob` but it can't work because I didn't add `@Configuration` at `BatchConfiguration`. class but it still work even no `@Configuration`. so I wonder How can`@Bean` `DataSource` inject without `@Configuration`? you can check second image what this project works.

so plz I wanna solve my wondering and you can see that full source in my github address and my English skill is not good

[image]
[image]

```
package com.bootbatch.job; 
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource; 
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment; 
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource; 
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource; 
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer; 
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator; 
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync; 
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling; 
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor; 
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler; 
import javax.sql.DataSource; 
@ComponentScan("com.bootbatch") 
@PropertySource("classpath:/database.properties") 
@EnableBatchProcessing 
public class BatchConfiguration { 
    @Autowired 
    private Environment env; 
    @Bean 
    public DataSource dataSource() { 
          DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(); 
          dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url")); 
          dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username")); 
          dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password")); 
          return dataSource; 
   } 
   @Bean 
   public DataSourceInitializer databasePopulator() { 
     System.out.println("===>databasePopulator에 접속!!"); 
         ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(); 
         populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql")); 
   //        populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("truncate_secondjob.sql")); 
         populator.setContinueOnError(true); 
         populator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true); 
         DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer(); 
         initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator); 
         initializer.setDataSource(dataSource()); 
         return initializer; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: its github address is https://github.com/namubada88/SpringBatch-dtoc-ctod

Comment: It works because you are creating a new configuration based on those classes. Which will make them components (not configuration classes!) and components can have `@Bean` methods as well (search the documenation for Bean Mode Lite) AND as it are now components they will be injected to. You are basically working around Spring Boot (you are starting Spring Boot, that stops and in your code you are creating a new context for those 2 classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is your own code in your `main` method (which you hapilly forgot to include in your question!).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootBatch06Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException, InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootBatch06Application.class, args);

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BatchConfiguration.class, BatchJob.class);

        // Other code removed
    }   
}
```

You are creating a new `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` for those 2 classes. Which will make those 2 classes components automatically (regardless of a `@Component` or `@Configuration` annotation). So you are basically working around Spring Boot and its auto-configuration (probably because it didn't work).

It is also allowed for `@Components` to have `@Bean` methods, they will operate in so called "lite @Bean Mode" (see [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts) of the Spring Reference Guide).

So because they are now first of all components (or beans) and have `@Bean` methods they will produce new beans (although not as you think they do, read the aformentioned documentation).